# Debugging custom actions

Tags: debugging, windows-installer, custom-action

I have a C++ Wix custom action which is used to browse for a file on the local computer.  When I run the installer on Windows Server 2003 and Windows 7 (my machine) it works as expected.  However, when I run the installer on Windows Server 2008, the custom action fails.

I have successfully set the MsiBreak environment variable and am able to attach my debugger using remote debugging.  When I do this, the custom action works as expected.  If I try again without the debugger attached, the custom action thread crashes without displaying the file open dialog (crash details below).  I have tried custom actions which use the common file dialog and the common item dialog and have the same result with both.

All my other custom actions work perfectly.  Does anyone have any ideas on how I should proceed?

Thanks!

`Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: MsiExec.exe
  Application Version:  5.0.7601.17514
  Application Timestamp:    4ce792c4
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.18409
  Fault Module Timestamp:   53159a86
  Exception Code:   80000003
  Exception Offset: 00013226
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789`

Comment: You should say something about what "the custom action fails" actually means. Is it a crash? Failure to show the dialog?

Comment: 80000003 is stackoverflow.

Comment: What I actually meant was where does it fail in your code. I ask because this could be a threading issue. If your code is not STA then anything related to windows and messages could fail, and of course it works in debug mode because Windows knows you may need UI and will get you an STA. Also this stuff is OS dependent, and unreliable in the execute sequence because it's MTA. For example if the crash is related to messages to UI window then you may get issues in a non-STA environment.  However you don't say where your CA is called from, deferred or not, or what your code is doing at the crash.

Comment: Sorry PhilDW.  I totally missed the theme of your comment.  :)  The custom action I am struggling with is an immediate custom action in the UI sequence.  Specifically, I have a dialog with a PushButton.  The PushButton has a DoAction ControlEvent which invokes a type 1 custom action.  Is there an easy way to detect where in my code the custom action is failing without the debugger? Or must I log a lot of messages?

Comment: Also, my custom action is a synchronous custom action which checks the value of the return code.

Comment: Must have been tired.  I'll update my custom action to write a minidump to see what I can find.

Comment: As before, make sure it's STA, but it should be anyway in the UI sequence unless you're off in COM. The call stack should help see what's going on. If you never see the dialog then that's a clue, or maybe it doesn't get that far.

Comment: Thanks PhilDW for continuing to help me out.  I don't specifically set the threading model.  Is there a way to do that?  Is there an easy way to check the threading model?

Answer (score 0):

Check in the **project's property pages** to determine what **threading settings** are there. I am not sure exactly where it is since I don't have Visual Studio available, but I found the picture underneath online. Look for something similar. And obviously set for all configurations (debug/release and x86 and x64):

Also have a look at some of the sample projects that are out there: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1747/MSI-Custom-Action-DLL

[image]